# Bluetooth is neither scanning devices nor visible in 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Today only I installed Ubuntu 18.04 but I am facing issue of Bluetooth.
Everything seems to be fine in it but while scanning, process continues for infinite time and not able to scan any device and not even visible in other devices as well. Some outputs are given below which may help:-

```
 shalender@shalender-SVF1521ASNB:~/$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [104d:90b8]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5729 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2717:ff88  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



      shalender@shalender-SVF1521ASNB:~/$ bluetoothctl
        [NEW] Controller 3C:77:E6:E3:F7:3E shalender-SVF1521ASNB [default]
        Agent registered
        [bluetooth]# power on
        Changing power on succeeded
        [bluetooth]# scan on
        Discovery started
        [CHG] Controller 3C:77:E6:E3:F7:3E Discovering: yes
        [CHG] Controller 3C:77:E6:E3:F7:3E DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
        [CHG] Controller 3C:77:E6:E3:F7:3E DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
        [CHG] Controller 3C:77:E6:E3:F7:3E Discoverable: yes


shalender@shalender-SVF1521ASNB:~/$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5729 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2717:ff88  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


shalender@shalender-SVF1521ASNB:~/$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   36.223354] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   36.223384] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   36.223390] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   36.223393] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   36.223403] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   36.750527] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   36.751486] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   36.767489] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   36.768491] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   36.907103] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd failed with error -2
[   36.907110] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd not found
[   38.912107] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   47.501405] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   47.501409] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   47.501420] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   51.460022] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   87.464271] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   87.464285] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   87.464296] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error

```
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd failed with error -2
```

You should install drivers suitable for your bluetooth interface

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -c https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd
```

Move or copie the firmware file in `/lib/firmware/brcm/`